# Can we achieve read on mutable data after write atomically in ConcurrentHashMap in Java?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to find an answer to these, but not able to understand(or confirm) it on Google or in Java docs.

My implementation looks like as this:

```
Map<String, POJO> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, POJO>();
```

if I do

```
value1 = map.get(key1);
value1.setProp(prop);
```

Any other thread may override.

Now, I'm thinking if I do like follows: would it be an atomic operation/in another words, it will block the key1 segment?

```
map.compute(key1, (key1, value1) -> { value1.setProp(prop) });
```

Javadoc for `compute` function

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current
>   mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping). The entire
>   method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update
>   operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while
>   computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and
>   simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this Map.

References:

1.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html
 2.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-

## EDIT:

for my final implementation, I did something like this as all threads share NewMap and at the end, I new list of POJOs
Abstract Data Type

```
    public class NewMap {

        private Map<String, POJO> map;
        private boolean isUpdatable;
        void NewMap(){
              isUpdatable = true;
              map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
        }

        void putPOJOProp1(String key, Type value) throws ReadOnlyException{

                  map.compute(key, (k,v) -> {
                           if(!isUpdatable) throw new ReadOnlyException();
                           if(k == null){ 
                              POJO p = new POJO();
                              p.setProp1(value);
                              v = p;
                           } else { 
                              v = v.setProp1(v)
                           }
             });
        }

        void putPOJOProp2....
        void putPOJOProp3....

        List<POJO> getAll() {
             isUpdatable = false;
             List<POJO> pojos;
             for(key: map.getKeys()) {
                  Pojo p = map.get(key);
                  p.setKey(key);
                  pojos.add(p);
             }
             return pojos;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter for confirmation. So, value to the ConcurrentHashMap need not be atomic?

Comment: Even if this blocks other threads from getting the value for key `key1` during the modification, it won't do anything about the case where another thread gets the value *first*, you start modifying the object, and the other thread tries to use the object while you're modifying it.

Comment: I guess in that case I can abstract out ConcurrentHashMap with only setOperation as that serves my purpose. But yeah it's valid point @user2357112

Comment: while `compute` is atomic as well as anything in the lambda, if you access the object directly or after an atomic operation e.g. `get` you might see an old value.

Comment: In Java 8 OracleJDK it uses a `synchronized` block around the `Node` to implement this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Javadoc for [ConcurrentHashMap.compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) states

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically.

Note, by comparison the `ConcurrentSkipListMap.compute` is NOT atomic.

A more compact form of Alexey Soshin's answer is

```
Map<String, long[]> map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
map.put("A", new long[2]);
IntStream.range(0, 1_000_000)
        .parallel()
        .forEach(i -> map.compute("A", (k, v) -> {
            v[0]++;
            v[1]++;
            return v;
        }));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map.get("A")));
```

prints something like

```
[643553, 597254]
```

c.f. HashMap produces something like

```
[244786, 245993]
```

However, use a `ConcurrentHashMap` and you get the expected

```
[1000000, 1000000]
```

Answer (score 9):

Your confusing two different terms.
`ConcurrentHashMap` prevents corruption of internal structure, but doesn't prevent race conditions. If all you want to avoid is data corruption, then use of `ConcurrentHashMap` is valid.
But from your question it seems that you're trying to avoid race conditions. `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't protect you from them in any way.

To understand it better, let's see the following example:

```
    Map<String, POJO> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(10);

    for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
        pool.execute(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                map.compute("A", (k, v) -> {
                    if (v == null) {
                        return new POJO();
                    }
                    v.a = ++v.a;
                    v.b = ++v.b;

                    return v;
                });
            }
        });
    }

    pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println(map);

    // With POJO like 
    class POJO {
       // toString() here
       Integer a = 1;
       Integer b = 1;
    }
```

Here we get `{A=POJO{a=1000000, b=1000000}}`, so our operation was thread safe. If that's all you want you get, you're fine.